# Avoid "push ebp, mov esp, ebp" prologue when no cleanup is required

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

I have an X86 ASM routine assembled with MASM/ML. The routine is [__cdecl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) and used within Visual Studio.

The routine does not use locals, but it does fetch arguments relative to `ebp`. Here's how the procedure is declared:

```masm
.CODE
ALIGN   8
OPTION LANGUAGE:C
...

MSC_ASM_GenerateBlock PROC arg1:DWORD,arg2:DWORD,arg3:DWORD

  Load_Arguments:
    mov     buffer, arg1
    mov     bsize,  arg2
    mov     safety, arg3
  ...

MSC_ASM_GenerateBlock ENDP
```

MASM is generating a standard prologue (`dumpbin` disassembly, labels are due to `/Zi`):

```
_MSC_ASM_GenerateBlock:
  00000000: push        ebp
  00000001: mov         ebp,esp

Load_Arguments:
  00000003: mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp+8]
  00000006: mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
  00000009: mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+10h]
...
```

And it is generating a standard epilogue (`dumpbin` disassembly, labels are due to `/Zi`):

```
  ...
MSC_ASM_GenerateBlock_Success:
  0000005B: mov         eax,1
MSC_ASM_GenerateBlock_Ret:
  00000060: leave
  00000061: ret
```

Because its `__cdecl`, I'm not responsible for callee cleanup. In addition I have nothing to clean. I'd like to avoid the prologue's `push` and `mov`, and the epilogue's `leave`.

How can I avoid the `push`, `mov` and `leave`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the prologue/epilogue with a pair of OPTIONs:

```
OPTION PROLOGUE:NONE 
OPTION EPILOGUE:NONE
```

And if you want restore the default for parts of the code:

```
OPTION PROLOGUE:PrologueDef 
OPTION EPILOGUE:EpilogueDef
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I actually came across it myself at [The MASM Forums](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=1476.0). Its too bad Microsoft did not feel it important enough to document it at [OPTION (MASM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zc781yh.aspx) (other than to list it).